# How can I get cheerio to work with CSS Manipulation?

Tags: javascript, express, axios, cheerio

My project is a webscraper using axios, cheerio and express. Every time I try to run the project, it errors out.

I am using my friend's website for a test page. This is the code I used:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const publicDir = app.use(express.static('public'))
var cheerio = require('cheerio'); // Basically jQuery for node.js
const { replaceWith } = require('cheerio/lib/api/manipulation');
const axios = require('axios').default;


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('/public/index.html')
})

app.get('/imagineoranges', (req, res) => {
  const $ = cheerio.load('/imagineoranges')
  axios.get("https://imagineoranges.neocities.org")
    .then(({data}) => res.send(data))
    .then( $('a:link').css("color: white;") )
    .then( $('a:visited').css("color: yellow;") )
    .then( $('a:hover').css("color: yellow;") )
    .then( $("body").css("@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik&display=swap'); background-color: #ff7300; color: white; font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;") ) 
})


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

The Result is:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:535
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/api/manipulation' is not defined by "exports" in /home/lucas/Desktop/UBlock/node_modules/cheerio/package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
    at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:292:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:602:3)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:529:36)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:569:31)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/lucas/Desktop/UBlock/index.js:6:25) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}

Node.js v19.0.1
```

Comment: `const $ = cheerio.load('/imagineoranges')` looks wrong. That should be the HTML string, not a URL. What are you trying to accomplish, exactly?

Comment: @ggorlen Fixed. I was trying to load the page and change the css to what was on the original css file. I tried to fix it but it is still spitting out the same error.

Comment: I fixed the page, the styles still aren't loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be providing the response HTML to Cheerio, manipulating the document and then rendering it to the response.

The styles you're trying to set look more like they should be done via CSS so consider inserting a `<style>` tag.

For example

```js
app.get("/imagineoranges", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get("https://imagineoranges.neocities.org", {
      responseType: "text",
    });
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);
    $("head").append(
      `<style type="text/css">@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik&display=swap);a:link,body{color:#fff}a:hover,a:visited{color:#ff0}body{background-color:#ff7300;font-family:Rubik,sans-serif}<style>`
    );
    res.set("content-type", "text/html").send($.root().html());
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(err.response?.status ?? 500).send(err.response?.data);
  }
});
```